# Move data from S3 to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3

I want to move bulk data (zip files) from s3 to PostgreSQL. Is there any Service/solution in AWS?

I tried Data pipeline but it doesn't have s3 to Postgres template.

I tried aws_s3 extension and copy command but these commands only work for csv,text,json and just on single files not in moving bulk data.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, I suspect that you can use AWS Data Pipeline to target an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database just like a MySQL database. However, you are right -- it will not operate on Zip files. You would need to extract the files first.

Comment: Why do you want to store ZIP files in a Postgres database? S3 seems to be a better choice for that.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your problem: do you want to store the zip file itself in Postgres, or only its content (like csv files)?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't have to be Zip files, I will extract them first. Basically these are backup files from existing Prod Databases(Postgres sql and mongoDB) Moving to S3, Now i am moving these files .bak(backup or tar) files to New Rds(Postgres ) server.
I want to migrate S3 data to RDS(postgres) every week but looks like there is no straight forward solution other than using data pipeline with Mysql template.